# I have matrix of 200*10 it has values between 50 and 150 I have to normalize it that is I want to see values less than one

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-coder

I have a matrix 200 *10 having values between 100 and 150 and I want to have values of between [0 1] that's it.

I know one way of doing is to divide it by max value but I want to know any other way i.e built in function of matlab or any other mathematical formula which shifts all values to less than one. Kindly do not mention sigmoid function as I have tried.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To normalize a matrix `X` such that values lies in the range `[0, 1]`, you can use:

```
Xnorm = (X - min(X(:)))/(max(X(:)) - min(X(:)))
```

Comment: Yes, bro it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dividing by a number is much more computationally expensive than a comparison. Try something like

```
m = max(A(:))
B = A(A<m)
```

This is called "logical indexing". The result will be a vector of values in `A` smaller than the maximum `m`. Of m doesn't have to be the maximum though... you could equally well substitute any value of `m` and logical indexing will work.

For instance, in the above code, if

```
A = 
[0     3     4
 2     0     4
 5     5     2
 4     5     3
 5     4     1 ]

B.' =  [ 0     2     4     3     0     4     4     4     2     3     1 ]
```

Let me know if this is what you had in mind. It was a bit unclear from the question.

Comment: You are right but here dimension is actually changed i.e 5*3 are now changed to any row or column vector which isn't required and also values are not less than one which I need values in between [0 1]

Comment: It was unclear from your wording... As I read it... you want to know the values in the matrix which are less than the maximum value. Did P0W's solution solve your problem? If not, please update the question to make it clear what the goal is.

Comment: I have updated.